# Are there promo codes for Mac App Store applications?

Tags: macos, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

Does Apple provide developers with promo codes for their Mac App Store applications? I can't find the options on iTunes Connect (it's there for our iOS apps, though), so I guess the answer would be "not at the moment"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news: [it is possible now](http://www.macstories.net/news/developers-you-can-now-generate-promo-codes-for-mac-apps/).

Comment: Thanks, just saw the news item! :)